# Why I cannot add the navbar shadow in this Boostrap 4 template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the navbar shadow in this Bootstrap 4.6 template without success:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/starter-template/

I've copied the navbar styles from this one (with shadow):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/pricing/

In particular, I'm referring to `box-shadow`, in the code below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow">
```

Comment: Please provide minimal working example. Maybe you have wrapper that hides your shadow with `overflow: hidden`, maybe you just assume that it's not there

Comment: You're a member with a really high reputation and have been on SO for 12 years, you know we need some code examples to help you figure out what's going wrong. This question is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the template you're using has changed/removed styles for the `box-shadow` declaration. I tried adding the class you mentioned on the template page and it doesn't result in any new styles being applied to the navbar. Are you sure you're:

- spelling the class name correctly?
- using a template that includes the necessary CSS class declarations for shadows?

I tried adding a `box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000` style (using the inspector) to the navbar in the template and it works.

Comment: It works, you are right. I'm surprised to see this difference between the two official Bootstrap 4 templates.